# Windows Task Scheduler does not execute php code in bat

Tags: php

I have set an Task in the Windows Task Scheduler for every 1 minute. This Task call an `bat` file with:

```
php "create.php"
```

The `bat` file and the `create.php` file are in the same folder. If i run the `bat` manuelly, it works. But if the Task Scheduler run this `bat`, my PHP code is not executed (but i see for an half second the CMD open).

This is my php script in the `create.php`:

```
$data = file_get_contents('data.txt');

file_put_contents('data.txt', $data. "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

The `data.txt` file has write access.

// Edit:

I set an `PAUSE` in my script. Error says: `could not open input file: create.php`

Comment: Is the running directory the same as the bat directory? What's the contents of `%cd%` ?

Comment: instead of putting `php "create.php"` try putting the full path of the create.php. Example: `php C:/xampp/htdocs/create.php`

Comment: Oh, i write `cd my/path` in my script, and it runs with `php create.php`. Thanks all! But `php c\:path/bla/create.php` doesn't work. No error.

Comment: I wanted to write answer but as you found it write it as vote as solved